# Redirect IP to Domain Name in AWS

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, laravel-6

I have a problem, My Domain Name is "example.com" and IP "00.00.00.000". When I search on browser with domain name that is "example.com". its working fine, but also my website indexed in Google with my "IP". And when I search on browser with my "IP" it also work. So, I need to redirect my IP to my domain "example.com". My website is hosted on AWS. What should I do Now? And I saw many solutions, some solutions was on .htaccess file, some on AWS

Comment: **Side-note:** When you enter a domain name into a browser, you are not "searching" -- you are telling the browser to go to that domain. Similarly, when you enter an IP address, you are also not "searching" -- you are telling the browser to go to that IP address.

Comment: "I saw many solutions, some solutions was on .htaccess file, some on AWS" - And? Did you try anything?!